# React Native Bluetooth App gives error on starting

Tags: javascript, react-native, bluetooth

I am a complete beginner to react native and I also don't know a lot about Bluetooth. But I want to learn about it. What I am trying to accomplish is to make an app where you can make a Bluetooth connection with another device. I found this youtube video that does exactly this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtMCKngZNHc&lc=Ugyk8-6704OwqD2MtnV4AaABAg

But when I download the code I can't figure out how to run it. Firstly I run `npm install`, and then `npm start` which boots up metro, the application loads on my Android device but when it starts an error pops up and says:

> "ERROR  TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[5], "./BleModule").BleModule.createClient')
> ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
> This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native."

I dont know what I'm doing wrong but I suspect I'm forgetting some commands or something. I have also been looking in to the bluetooth packages of react native, but I cant seem to figure out how to make them work. Does someone know any good tutorials for react native + bluetooth connections, how to correctly setup such a project. Hopefully you guys can help me!

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial uses [react-native-ble-plx](https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx) which has many problems.

I suggest that the best way to develop functions such as bluetooth is to use Native, and then let Native communicate with React Native through NativeModules.